# Is there a Midnight Commander log or history file?

Tags: logging, command-line-interface

Sometimes I have to track down user activity on remote machines. Linux audit and messages log are of course a great help; .bash_history is also very helpful, but it's not very verbose as a lot of people here just use Midnight Commander for running everything. I've tried to find some kind of log file for Midnight Commander, but found nothing.

My question is: does MC do any kind of user activity logging at all? If so, where it stores the data, and how to obtain it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a whole subdirectory `~/.mc/`, and `~/.local/share/mc/`. This said, using audit log is much more helpful in tracking down activity since it is supposed to catch all pertinent events.

Answer (score 1):

No, I have never known MC to have any logging mechanism.  Other than for the FTP functionality.

For high risk file systems, you will want to keep high frequency backups and restrict access or the tools to access such areas.

No logging, but some very light history, as @Deer Hunter has shown.  However, not suitable for auditing.  Does not log deleting or moving files, etc.